# selenium - not able to select li from ul

Tags: selenium, html-lists, dropdown

i have a dropdown in the form of ul-li.

in order to select required value from it, i am clicking on the dropdown first and then trying to select the li. however  its not working.

i tried couple of ways-
1. using select class of selenium
2. performing click operation on li
however it did not work.

code:

```
//this line works - to click on the dropdown to make all values visible
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='select2-Crm_Leads_FIRSTNAME_SALUTATION-container']/span")).click();


//this line does not work       
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='select2-Crm_Leads_FIRSTNAME_SALUTATION-result-jolq-Mr.']/span")).click();
```

pls refer to attached screenshot showing html page details of these controls.
is there any way i can select "mr." value from dropdown here? or am i doing anything wrong here.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? What error do you see?

Comment: it throws  elementnotfound exception

Comment: error is correct, you didn't click on the proper ul

Comment: i tried with below approach and it worked for me                                       
 // Get all of the options
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='select2-Crm_Leads_FIRSTNAME_SALUTATION-results']/li"));
                                                                                              // Loop through the options and select the one that matches
   for (WebElement opt : options) {
    System.err.println(opt);
    if (opt.getText().equals("Mr.")) {
     opt.click();
     return;
    }
   }